# Powershell ForEach & ForEach-Object with Select

Tags: powershell

i was trying to loop through a list of file names in $s4a using ForEach and ForEach-Object and display output. The only two ways i found that generate output are:

- ForEach ($name in $s4a) {$name.Name}
- $s4a| ForEach-Object {$_ | Select Name}

Can someone please let me know why the ones below generate nothing, while the above two work?

- ForEach ($name in $s4a) {Select Name} #No result
- ForEach ($name in $s4a) {Select $name.Name} #No result
- $s4a| ForEach-Object {Select$_.Name} #No result
- $s4a| ForEach-Object {Select Name} #No result

Thanks heaps!

Comment: Well, because that's not how `Select-Object` works, basically. An expression like `Select Name` is valid, but results in nothing because `Select-Object` takes its input from the pipeline, unless `-InputObject` is used. Since there is no pipeline in your `foreach` loops, or in the blocks you pass to `ForEach-Object`, there is no output. Using `-InputObject` you can get each of your examples to output something, although there would be little point since it's just more verbose.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between select-object and using foreach on the same object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26315734/difference-between-select-object-and-using-foreach-on-the-same-object)

Comment: thanks @jrider for sharing the link - it looks to me "Select -InputObject " can essentially replace ForEach loop in listing out elements inside a variable and hopefully improve on performance?

Comment: Correct, if you are just needing to display members of your object, a simple select statement is much faster. Also, if you want to get fancy with it you should look into select [calculated properties](https://4sysops.com/archives/add-a-calculated-property-with-select-object-in-powershell/). In your case just put `$s4a | select Name` or `$s4a.Name`

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, it's because your syntax is incorrect for each of the statements that aren't working.  In each of the non-working examples, you are not properly referencing the object that you wish the view the 'name' property on.

Select-Object is generally used when accepting an input object from the pipeline but can also identify the object using the -InputObject parameter.

When calling an object property by $object.propertyName, you don't need a select statement.

Instead of `ForEach ($name in $s4a) {Select Name}`, try this: `ForEach ($name in $s4a) {$name | Select Name}`

Instaed of `ForEach ($name in $s4a) {Select $name.Name}`, try this: `ForEach ($name in $s4a) {$name.Name}`

Instead of `$s4a| ForEach-Object {Select$_.Name}`, try this: `$s4a| ForEach-Object {$_.Name}`

Instead of `$s4a| ForEach-Object {Select Name}`, try this: `$s4a| ForEach-Object {$_ | Select Name}`

Also, please note that there is a difference in how each method returns information.  Select statements return modified versions of the original objects that only contain the properties that you are selecting.  Whereas, calling a property directly returns only the value of that property.

Comment: Thanks so much Ian-Mor! this is really helpful and much appreciate the detailed explanation. do you mind if i ask if it's correct say you should never us "Select $object.propertyName" in any instance? i kinda recall seeing this expression somewhere before but unsure how it worked, if you would have any idea?

Comment: Another question if you wouldnt mind - can "Select -InputObject " basically replace ForEach/ForEach-Object loop if i were to simply list out elements inside a variable? this way a loop is saved and performance is faster i assume?

Comment: If you want to view a property, you can just call it directly: "$object.propertyName".